# How to identify the element using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to identify the element. I want to identify the "address your concerns.". I am able to reach up to div tag but i need to reach the text in the div tag.

HTML:

```
<span class="Linkify">
    <div>
        <div>
            address your concerns. 
        </div> 
    </div>
</span>
```

I am trying to identify the text "address your concerns" so can anyone help me with this in chrome browser, I am trying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To identify the element using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `visibilityOfElementLocated()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  WebElement cssElement = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("span.Linkify > div > div")));
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  WebElement xpathElement = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[@class='Linkify']/div/div[contains(., 'address your concerns')]")));
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it using XPath to locate your div element, something like this "//span[@class='Linkify']/div/div" and then use getText() method on this div to get your text.

Comment: //span[@class='Linkify']/div/div[contains(text(), 'address your dry eye concerns.')]  I need without using getText()method   with this can able to reach upto second div tag